# Combine different predicate filter types?

Tags: angularjs

I wish to know if it is possible to combine different filter predicate types: string and function.

You can see in this template how I try to chain them with ":". They work well apart, but not together :

```
Search: <input ng-model="query">

<div ng-controller="ListProscontroller" ng-init="listpros()">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in prosItems.results | filter:idfilter:query"> {{item.firstName}} </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the function in the controller:

```
$scope.idfilter = function (myids) {
            return myids.firstName == "Benjamin" || myids.firstName == "Rob";

        };
```

This is for illustration purpose, but I will have this function to filter result to only show those ids present in the function (favorites) and run the "query" string on those favorites only.
I wish to know if with default angular syntax is it possible to do so, if not, then where to investigate to achieve such a thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
ng-repeat="item in prosItems.results | filter:idfilter | filter:query"
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what I needed. I will get those ids from a get. Because there can be quite a bit, once I get them is the best way to cycle trough them in this function is to use a regular javascript loop right  ?